# Displaying the number of iterations - C++

Tags: c++

Here's the code to find Lychrel numbers (it's not perfect as of yet, but that's not important to the question:

```
#include <iostream>

int Reverse(int number)
{
    int rem = 0;
    while (number > 0)
    {
    rem = (rem * 10) + (number % 10);
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return rem;

}

bool is_Palindrome(int num)
{
    return (num == Reverse(num));
}

bool isLychrel(int num, const int iterCount = 50)

{
    int temp = num;
    int rev;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
    {

        rev = Reverse(temp);
        if (is_Palindrome(rev + temp))
            return false;
        temp = temp + rev;
    }
    return true;

}

int main()
{

    bool l = isLychrel(some number);
    std::cout << l << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

What I want to do is, other than to display whether or not it is a Lychrel number, I want to show how many iterations it took for the palindrome to be discovered. So I know I have to define an int i = 0, but I don't know where and I don't know how to make it work. I tried to do it outside of the loop, like this:

```
int i = 0;
{
    int temp = num;
    int rev;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
    {

        rev = Reverse(temp);
        if (is_Palindrome(rev + temp))
            return false;
        temp = temp + rev;
    }
    return true;

}
```

but I get the error "expected unqualified-id before "{" token" and "expected initializer before 'int'". I'm at a loss on where to put it to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse "i" outside of the loop then you need to take the initialiser out of the for loop.

**Change this**

```
for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
```

**To this**

```
for ( i < iterCount; i++)
```

Otherwise I would suggest using a while loop.

**Edit:** For more information on variable scope I would recommend [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-1a-local-variables-and-local-scope/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure what your problem really is. Your function "isLychrel" currently returns false if the input is known not to a Lychrel number within the input max number of iterations, and true otherwise. Do you want your function to also return the actual number of iterations that executed? If so you could provide a reference to an integer variable in the signature to receive the actual number of iterations.

That is, your function could look like this

```
 bool isLychrel(int num, int& ornNumIters, const int iterCount = 50)
 {
    int temp = num;
    int rev;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; i++)
    {

         rev = Reverse(temp);
         if (is_Palindrome(rev + temp))
         {
             ornNumIters = i; 
             return false;
         }
         temp = temp + rev;
    }
    ornNumIters = iterCount; 
    return true;
}
```

and you would call it like :

```
 int nActualIterations = 0; 
 bool bResult = isLychrel(89,nActualIterations);
```